# Floating list elements to right instead of down

Tags: html

I would like to float list elements to the right using a list (I like the bullet points), and want to stay away from tables. I would also like to customize the space between the list items, and specify when the list items wrap. For example, 3 list items per "row."

Example picture:

[image]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `display: inline` style on your `li` element will get your list flowing horizontally. Further styling (such as `padding` and `margin`) can let you manipulate the space between the items, and `list-style-type` will even let you customize the appearance of the bullet.

I'm not aware of any simple means to specify on which item the list will break to a newline, though. It should simply wrap when it reaches the edge of its container. (You could specify the width of the list, although that will change which item the list breaks on depending on the user's font size.)

Comment: Thanks Brian. So I guess if I really wanted to concretely specify that a row breaks on 3 columns and doesn't change based on the user's font size, should I use a table? If so, how could I achieve the above with a table?

Comment: @Growler, If you want tabular information (such as, for example, two rows of three columns each), then yes, a table is the correct markup choice. If you want a list of items (horizontally or not, wrapping in their container or not), then a list is the correct markup choice. (If the list is meant to have a natural order, an ordered list is the correct choice.) Consider: your HTML tells the browser _what_ is on the page, your CSS tells the browser _how it should look_, and your JavaScript tells the browser _how it should behave_.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
li {
  float: left;
}
```

if you want them to go on multiple lines like your example then set a width on the ul like so:

```
ul {
  width: 200px;
}
```

(200px is just an example number)

Answer (score 0):

try to style  with css

```
ul{
width: //configure with your self until 3 list/row
}

li{
display:inline;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: This floats it horizontally, but doesn't allow me to specify spacing between each list item.

Answer (score 0):

Can be some like thus:

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/LK7rd/

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
ul{
    width: 50%;
}

ul li{
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Is this based on the Item name being the same length each time? I have variable lengthed list items, and it breaks the word awkwardly