# Float masonary elements to the right instead of stacking

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working off of this **[snippit](http://www.bootply.com/118335)** to create a masonary style homepage. However I don't want to stack the div elements, rather gradually float them to the right and tile downward.

I've seen this **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908792/floating-list-elements-to-right-instead-of-down)**, but it's in regards to list elements, I can't seem to get it work with div elements. I don't want to use a jquery plugin to handle this FYI, I want to keep it pure CSS.

Comment: Without a code example, its hard to say what the issue is.

Comment: Code snipits are linked in the post.

Comment: ah, its because `column-width` on `row` class is restricting the column size. You should remove that and set fixed width on the `item` class: http://www.bootply.com/5kpYEJvtZS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your masonary the css property [column-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width) to limit the size of the column and stack the divs vertically.

If you want to simply have the divs flow horizontally and overflow vertically, all you need to do is set the `item` to `display:inline-block` and set a fixed width:

```
.item {
 display: inline-block;
 padding:  .25rem;
 width:  200px;
}
```

[code example](http://www.bootply.com/5kpYEJvtZS)

Comment: Worked great. I also added  `vertical-align: text-top;` to push the content up so it aligned horizontally.